# "Cannot dispatch without an AsyncContext" when serving files

Tags: java, spring-mvc, asynchronous, servlet-3.0

I need to write a "disposable file download" MVC controller on top of a "file download controller". Once a file has been transferred to the client, it must be deleted from the server.

Initially, the code was written to serve files

import org.springframework.core.io.Resource

```
@GetMapping("/get/{someParam}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(Long someParam)
{

    Long fileId = identify(someParam);

    return super.downloadFile(fileId); //This uses a "File repository" service binding file IDs to physical paths

}

protected ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(Long fileId){

    File theFile = resolve(fileId);

    return new FileSystemResource(theFile);

}
```

Since the ResponseEntity is some kind of "future" entity, I can't delete the file in a finally block because it won't be served yet.

So I wrote an async version of file download first, leveraging Commons IO to copy the payload. Then I leveraged the callbacks in order to dispose of the file from only my method.

```
protected WebAsyncTask<Void> downloadFileAsync(Long fileId,HttpResponse response){ //API method for multiple uses across the application

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(resolve(fileId));
    Callable<Void> ret = () -> {
        IOUtils.copy(is,response.getOutputStream());
        is.close();
        return null;
    };


    return ret;
}

@GetMapping("/get/{someParam}")
public WebAsyncTask<Void> downloadFile(Long someParam,HttpResponse response)
{
    Long fileId = identify(someParam);
    WebAsyncTask ret = downloadFileAsync(fileId,response);


    ret.onCompletion(()-> fileService.delete(fileId)); //Here I leverage the callback because this file, in this point, is disposable

    return ret;
}
```

When I run the second version, I get the following error. Server is Tomcat 8.0.50

```
10-Sep-2018 12:20:37.551 AVVERTENZA [ajp-nio-8009-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.setErrorState onError() failed for listener of type [org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncListenerWrapper]
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot dispatch without an AsyncContext
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.dispatch(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.setConcurrentResultAndDispatch(WebAsyncManager.java:369)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.access$200(WebAsyncManager.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager$3.handle(WebAsyncManager.java:311)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.onError(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncListenerWrapper.fireOnError(AsyncListenerWrapper.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.setErrorState(AsyncContextImpl.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:370)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.asyncDispatch(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:745)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:666)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have configured all servlets and filters to support async operation in my `web.xml`. I did some research and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24730642/471213) was no help because I am using a newer Tomcat version.

What is wrong with my code? I have not posted it entirely to keep it simply simple, but debugging I see that the write operation succeeds with correct payload.

Comment: Don't use `WebAsyncTask` that is intended for internal use. Just use a `CompletableFuture` or return a `Callable`. If you put the `try/finally` inside your `Callable` it will work.

Comment: Can you kindly expand? I thought WebAsyncTask was a wrapper for the callable ad an (optional) executor, falling back to the default executor

Comment: It is used internally by the `WebAsyncTask` to wrap a callable and call specific methods on that and constructing a async context. You cannot do that in your method hence it won't work. But as stated just place everything in your `Callable` and simply return that from the method and it will work.

Comment: Any luck solving this? I just started hitting this issue as well. Happens 50% of the times when client closes the connection before complete response has been sent.

Comment: I fixed using @M.Deinum's comment. Simply, `WebAsyncTask` is **not** an API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @MDenium's comment

> Don't use WebAsyncTask that is intended for internal use. Just use a CompletableFuture or return a Callable. If you put the try/finally inside your Callable it will work

WebAsyncTask is just not an API, so Spring doesn't know how to handle it when you return from an MVC method. It's not the correct way to perform async execution. It is used only internally to carry the task and the context.

Spring MVC supports:

- DeferredResult
- Callable
- CompletableFuture

and probably a **few** others

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with serving files when using Callable in combination with spring.mvc.async.request-timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, the solution was to configure an `AsyncTaskExecutor`:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(-1);
        configurer.setTaskExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
        // an implementaiton of AsyncTaskExecutor
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("async");
    }

}
```