# Spring REST endpoint returning StreamingResponseBody: AsyncRequestTimeoutException after 30 seconds

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-rest

I have the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877498/async-timeout-downloading-a-large-file-using-streamingresponsebody-on-spring-boo/43496244#43496244) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947789/restcontroller-with-streamingresponsebody-async-request-timeout-not-working).

I tried the answers given and combinations thereof but none solved my issue.

When I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57671503/1781376) answer, after 30 seconds, instead of the timeout, the download restarted from the beginning and then, after 30 more seconds, then it timed out.

I'm testing by visiting the REST endpoint in Google Chrome and trying to download a file from there.

[Here](https://github.com/GuiRitter/TransfererLocal) I have the project that displays this error.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** here's the source:

> src\main\java\io\github\guiritter\transferer_local\TransfererLocalApplication.java

```java
package io.github.guiritter.transferer_local;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class TransfererLocalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TransfererLocalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> src\main\java\io\github\guiritter\transferer_local\DefaultController.java

```java
package io.github.guiritter.transferer_local;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController;
// import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;

@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class DefaultController {

    @Value("${fileName}")
    private String fileName;

    @Value("${filePath}")
    private String filePath;

    @GetMapping("download")
    public StreamingResponseBody downloadHub(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath + fileName);
        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", file.length() + "");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        return outputStream -> {
            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[1024*1024];
            while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        };
    }

    // @GetMapping("download")
    // public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadHub(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    //  File file = new File(filePath + fileName);
    //  response.setContentType(APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
    //  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    //  response.setHeader("Content-Length", file.length() + "");
    //  InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    //  return ResponseEntity.ok(outputStream -> {
    //      int nRead;
    //      byte[] data = new byte[1024*1024];
    //      while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    //          outputStream.write(data, 0, nRead);
    //      }
    //      inputStream.close();
    //  });
    // }
}
```

> src\main\java\io\github\guiritter\transferer_local\AsyncConfiguration.java

```java
package io.github.guiritter.transferer_local;

// import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.AsyncSupportConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public AsyncTaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("io.github.guiritter.transferer_local.async_executor_thread.");
        return executor;
    }

    /** Configure async support for Spring MVC. */
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurerAdapter(
            AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {

            @Override
            public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer
                        .setDefaultTimeout(Long.MAX_VALUE)
                        .setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
                configureAsyncSupport(configurer);
            }
        };
    }

    // @Autowired
    // private AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    // /** Configure async support for Spring MVC. */
    // @Bean
    // public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
    //  return new WebMvcConfigurer() {

    //      @Override
    //      public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
    //          configurer
    //                  .setDefaultTimeout(Long.MAX_VALUE)
    //                  .setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    //          configureAsyncSupport(configurer);
    //      }
    //  };
    // }
}
```

> src\main\java\io\github\guiritter\transferer_local\MyConfiguration.java

```java
package io.github.guiritter.transferer_local;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.AsyncSupportConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAsync
public class MyConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(-1);
    }
}
```

> src\main\resources\application.properties

```
server.port=8081
fileName=large_file_name.txt
filePath=C:\\path\\to\\large\\file\\

# spring.mvc.async.request-timeout = 9223372036854775807
# spring.mvc.async.request-timeout = 2147483647
spring.mvc.async.request-timeout = -1
```

> pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.github.guiritter</groupId>
    <artifactId>transferer-local</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>TransfererLocal</name>
    <description>Enables local network file transfer</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Update:** trying Manuel's answer (commited to branch answer_Manuel):

> src\main\java\io\github\guiritter\transferer_local\DefaultController.java

```java
package io.github.guiritter.transferer_local;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncTask;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;

@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class DefaultController {

    @Value("${fileName}")
    private String fileName;

    @Value("${filePath}")
    private String filePath;

    @GetMapping("download")
    public WebAsyncTask<ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>> downloadHub(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath + fileName);
        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", file.length() + "");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        return new WebAsyncTask<ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>>(Long.MAX_VALUE, () ->

            ResponseEntity.<StreamingResponseBody>ok(outputStream -> {

                int nRead;
                byte[] data = new byte[1024*1024];
                while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(data, 0, nRead);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            })
        );
    }
}
```

It threw `AsyncRequestTimeoutException` and this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot dispatch without an AsyncContext
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.dispatch(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.setConcurrentResultAndDispatch(WebAsyncManager.java:391) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startCallableProcessing$2(WebAsyncManager.java:315) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.lambda$onError$0(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:146) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.onError(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:146) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncListenerWrapper.fireOnError(AsyncListenerWrapper.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.setErrorState(AsyncContextImpl.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:237) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:59) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

**Update:** trying Manuel's updated answer (commited to branch answer_Manuel_2020-04-06):

> src\main\java\io\github\guiritter\transferer_local\DefaultController.java

```java
package io.github.guiritter.transferer_local;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncTask;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;

@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class DefaultController {

    @Value("${fileName}")
    private String fileName;

    @Value("${filePath}")
    private String filePath;

    @GetMapping("download")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadHub() throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath + fileName);
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
                .header("Content-Length", file.length() + "")
                .<StreamingResponseBody>body(outputStream -> {
                    int nRead;
                    byte[] data = new byte[1024*1024];
                    while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(data, 0, nRead);
                    }
                    inputStream.close();
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include the relevant Code form your Github Projekt right in your question? In case the Project gets deleted (or updated), we still have the code in your question. That enables other users, having the same problem, to reproduce and find appropriate answer.

Comment: @Manuel I did. I didn't do it before because I intend to keep it available on GitHub at least for as long as I'm alive and because a Spring project requires a few different files, making the question take quite a lot of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To fix the problem:**

Change `@RepositoryRestController` to e.g., `@RestController`.

If you use `@RepositoryRestController`, the timeout will be set for the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. But upon requesting the download, the `RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter` handles the request, as the annotation requires him to.

If you use the `@RestController` then the (correct) `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` will handle the download, with the timeout set to -1.

**The original answer:**

You could try to declarative/explicit define the timeout, by returning a [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncTask](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/WebAsyncTask.html).

If offers to set a [`Callable<V>` with a `timeout`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/WebAsyncTask.html#WebAsyncTask-long-java.util.concurrent.Callable-):

Then your DefaultController could look like:

```
public WebAsyncTask<ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>> downloadHub() throws IOException {
  ...
  new WebAsyncTask<ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>>(myTimeOutAsLong, callable);
}
```

Update:

1. Please remove the `HttpServletResponse` parameter from your REST controller method. Just to be sure, that the `OutputStream` from the `HttpServletResponse` does not interfere with the `OutputStream` from `StreamingResponseBody`.
2. Regarding the error ´Cannot dispatch without an AsyncContext´: ["Cannot dispatch without an AsyncContext" when serving files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52255773/cannot-dispatch-without-an-asynccontext-when-serving-files)

Comment: I tried but it still fails. It's different with your solution that, after 30 seconds, the download always resets instead of dropping the download speed to 0 and staying there. Then, every 30 seconds after that, it resets again. See the edited first post for more information.

Comment: How do you initiate the download? Via browser? Javascript or HTML? Can you show us that piece of information as well?

Comment: I updated the first post to contain that information as well: "I'm testing by visiting the REST endpoint in Google Chrome and trying to download a file from there."

Comment: Unfortunately, no, same results. Regarding #2, I had already tried that.

Comment: Updated my answer, it will fix your problem.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Been a while since I accepted an answer here, I have forgotten about that...

Comment: I'm returning a WebAsyncTask with a 5 minute timeout, but it still throws AsyncRequestTimeoutException after 30 seconds. This solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Ask a separate question containing a minmal code snippet to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This doesn't work, as WebAsyncTask and StreamingResponseBody are unrelated, so timeout in one won't apply to timeout in second.